# Was Everyman using super powers he doesn't have?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

When I was watching the *The Flash* episode, *The Trap* ([S01E20](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trap)), I noticed this one strange thing:

> When Hannibal Bates, also known as Everyman was in the late part of the episode pretending to be Doctor Wells, he was vibrating his hand like he was also a speedster.

But earlier in this series, it was mentioned that he does not gain the power from the metahuman he touches. So how was he vibrating his hand?

Is this Everyman's natural behavior in the comics, or was this a mistake in the episode?

Comment: I'll have to review the scene, but I don't remember Wells' hand vibrating at all; I just remember him holding it up like he was *going* to start vibrating it

Comment: The error in your recollection is that wells did vibrate his hands, in that guys dream, earlier in the episode.

Comment: This made me think of another good question, but I'll post it as a separate one. How the heck did he know WHAT to do?

Comment: @Omegacron I am pretty sure he was well instructed by Wells on how to act it properly. But yea, there was clearly not enough time for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are incorrect.  He simply raises his hand mimicking Wells, but his hand does not vibrate.  This was the second hint that he is not Wells.  See:

[image: Wells looking for a high five]

Comment: [The scene is on YouTube, if anybody wants to verify](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jWhomZdqQ8)

Comment: What was the first hint that he was not Wells?

Comment: @Taladris The first hint for me was the fact that Wells took of his glasses and put on "I am sad that it came this fast" face, just the moment before this scene.

Comment: @FanaticD: but Wells (the real one) does not wear his glasses when he kills Cisco for the first time.

Comment: @Taladris He walked through the anti-speedster force field.

Comment: @Taladris That is not what I meant. I meant the time he was leaving Cortex after Katie told him, Cisco is down there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm episode 19 after copying flash he was able to speed up some but not as fast as flash himself. My theory is he's able to copy powers but only to an extent.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to contradict the question that he doesn't gain any power at all.  Do you have any evidence that he does?